# DoesNotExist at /accounts/profile/ balance matching query does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I can successfully login with profile page displaying username but as soon as I add balance variable I am getting "balance matching query does not exist" error.

Also the admin is not showing the model created
"accounts" is name of the app

I have added app name in settings.py

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class balance(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import balance
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            instance = balance(user = request.user, balance = 0)
            instance.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})

def profile(request):

    user = balance.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'profile.html',{"balance":user.balance})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import signup,profile

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('signup/', signup, name='signup'),
    path('profile/', profile, name='profile'),
```

**profile.html**

```
Hello {{request.user.username}} !! <br><br>
Balance:{{balance}}
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
```

Comment: How about just 'Balance: {{ request.user.balance.balance }}'?

Comment: can you share your urls.py file of both app (if you created one) and project.

Comment: Added urls.py for the app "accounts"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer of the second question of the admin. Did you register your Class to your (admin.py) file.
If don't you should go to the (admin.py) file and type:

`from .models import Your Class`

`admin.site.register(Your Class)`